# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'y.Font.isLoaded')

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-application

I am working on the Currency Converter app course by handlebarlabs. I am trying to add icons to my ScrollView ListItem by importing Ionicons from @expo/vector-icons.

Can anyone guide me what did I do wrongly?

Below are my code as per the course notes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { ListItem, Separator } from '../components/List';

const ICON_PREFIX = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios' : 'md';
const ICON_COLOR = '#868686';
const ICON_SIZE = 23;

class Options extends Component {
    handleThemesPress = () => {
        console.log('Press Themes');
    }

    handleSitePress = () => {
        console.log('Site Press');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <StatusBar translucent={false} barStyle={"default"} />
                <ListItem 
                    text="Themes"
                    onPress={this.handleThemesPress}
                    customIcon={
                        <Ionicons name={`${ICON_PREFIX}-arrow-forward`} size={ICON_SIZE} color={ICON_COLOR} />
                    }
                />
                <Separator/>
                <ListItem 
                    text="Fixer.io"
                    onPress={this.handleSitePress}
                    customIcon={
                        <Ionicons name={`${ICON_PREFIX}-link`} size={ICON_SIZE} color={ICON_COLOR} />
                    }
                />
                
                <Separator/>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

export default Options;
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'y.Font.isLoaded')
This error is located at:
   in p
   in RCTView
   in RCTView
   in TouchableHighlight
   in f
   in RCTScrollContentView
   in RCTScrollView
   in u
   in l
   in Unknown
   in v
   in RCTView
   in RCTView
   in c
```

Comment: If your Expo SDK is outdated try updating it to the latest. check out this link to update: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/  hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I created snack with Ionic Example by reusing your code that was posted in question.
Please check the versions in package.json and expo sdk in your project also.
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/ionicons

Comment: I was already on SDK 35 but reinstalling the SDK solves the issue. Thank you